# Get custom attribute for checkbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

How do i get custom attribute "mem_name" value ?

```
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3"  mem_name='ABC' name="checkmember" >
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  mem_name='PQR' name="checkmember" >

   <input type="button" onclick="resend_invite">

 function resend_invite() {
    if ($('input[name="checkmember"]:checked').length > 0) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send invite to selected Member?')) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkmember');
            var vals = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked)
                {
                    vals += checkboxes[i].$(value).attr('mem_id');
                    vals += ",";
                }
            }
            alert(vals);
            return false;
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var valsArray = new Array();
            valsArray = vals.split(",");
        }
    } else {
        alert('Please select at least one Member');
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want output like ABC,PQR.
I used "vals+=checkboxes[i].$(value).attr('mem_id');"
but it's not working.

Comment: try this $('.messageCheckbox').attr('mem_name'); will help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(checkboxes[i])` in order to get a jquery object with its `operations` and `properties` associated.

```
$(checkboxes[i]).attr('mem_name')
```

```js
function resend_invite() {
   if ($('input[name="checkmember"]:checked').length > 0) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send invite to selected Member?')) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkmember');
            var vals = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked)
                {
                    vals += $(checkboxes[i]).attr('mem_name');
                    vals += ",";
                }
            }
            alert(vals);
            return false;
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var valsArray = new Array();
            valsArray = vals.split(",");
        }
    } else {
        alert('Please select at least one Member');
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3"  mem_name='ABC' name="checkmember" >
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  mem_name='PQR' name="checkmember" >

   <input type="button" onclick="resend_invite()" value="Resend">
```

You can do this with pure `javascript`, using `getAttribute` method.

```js
function resend_invite() {
   if ($('input[name="checkmember"]:checked').length > 0) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send invite to selected Member?')) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkmember');
            var vals = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked)
                {
                    vals += checkboxes[i].getAttribute('mem_name');
                    vals += ",";
                }
            }
            alert(vals);
            return false;
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var valsArray = new Array();
            valsArray = vals.split(",");
        }
    } else {
        alert('Please select at least one Member');
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3"  mem_name='ABC' name="checkmember" >
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  mem_name='PQR' name="checkmember" >

   <input type="button" onclick="resend_invite()" value="Resend">
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
vals += checkboxes[i].$(value).attr('mem_id');
```

To

```
vals += $(checkboxes[i]).attr('mem_id');
```

Comment: @SwapnilW, what about my answer ?

Comment: @SwapnilW, don't forget to accept an answer in order to help other people.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai. sure i will follow it onwards

Comment: @SwapnilW, have a look here : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work in order to see how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this fiddle.Hope it works. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ritwika/e549Lxwr/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#memAdd").click(function(){
  if ($('input[name="checkmember"]:checked').length > 0) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send invite to selected Member?')) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkmember');
            var vals = [];
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked)
                {
                    vals += $(checkboxes[i]).attr('mem_name');
                    vals += ",";
                }
            }
            alert(vals);
            return false;
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var vals = vals.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            var valsArray = new Array();
            valsArray = vals.split(",");
        }
    } else {
        alert('Please select at least one Member');
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3"  mem_name='ABC' name="checkmember" >
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  mem_name='PQR' name="checkmember" >

   <input type="button" id="memAdd"  value="memAdd">
```